# How to change header text theme of time picker in flutter

Tags: flutter, timepicker

[Screen shot of time picker dialogue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPOrr.jpg)
In default header text theme in time picker is primary color of theme data.
How can customize time picker of header text theme?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the copyWith of the current theme and change the specific property that you need [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ThemeData/copyWith.html) you can find more information about the copyWith method.

You can look [here](https://flutterbyexample.com/flutter-theme-class/) how to implement a change in certain change of the current theme.

Comment: I changed primary color with  Copywith method in Theme constructor.But no change get same result.